# Mechanism of Dow's process

Tags: organic-chemistry

Does Dow's process follow Benzyne mechanism or ArSn2 mechanism?In some books I have seen that Dow's process to convert halobenzene to phenol follows ArSn2 mechanism.But nucleophilic substitution in benzene ring mostly follows benzyne mechanism.

Comment: Benzyne Mechanism (more specifically, elimination-addition mechanism) are followed only in the cases where we use nucleophiles, which can also act as strong bases. Whereas, Addition-Elimination mechanism is followed in all the other cases. $\ce{OH-}$ is not  a strong enough base to perform Substitution reaction by Benzyne mechanism. It generally undergoes $S_N Ar$ (Addition-Elimination) Mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Soumik.Your answer is quite satisfactory.

Comment: But isn't OH- a strong base? In such a case it would form a benzyne intermediate, right?